# Возможно ли создание ЧПУ?

Tags: php, чпу

Возможно ли создание ЧПУ на пхп(связь с БД) без внесения изменении в htaccess? 
Есть примеры?

Comment: совсем без изменений нельзя, надо все запросы отправить на index.php варианты - изменение в vhost (ну или можно без апача, просто сервер на php запустить)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще без .htaccess практически не возможно. Исключение - вы сконфигурируете свой сервер соответствующим способом. Хотя не думаю, что это легкий выход из положения. А вот избежать лишней головной боли с mod_rewrite можно. Я уже говорил тут об этом, но не могу найти этот пост, поэтому вкратце повторюсь. Создается правило, с помощью которого все запросы перенаправляются на морду, если директории или файла не существует физически на сервере. Например, так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Теперь, вы ловите такие запросы в php:

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Разбираете полученную строку "на запчасти": по слешу для определения основных частей URI, учитывая окончание, если допустим адрес может быть /some_path/page.html и в зависимости от полученных данных, выводите ту или иную информацию.

Comment: > для чего нужно исключать

Никто не говорил, что это нужно делать в обязательном порядке, но делается только из соображений возможных в том потребностей. Если у вас нет в планах открывать определенные директории, то естественно, что можно обойтись и без вышеуказанной строки. А "секьюрность" всё-таки надо повышать более радикальными способами ;)

Answer (score -2):

Да, возможно, такое ЧПУ сделано в CMS WordPress. Пример написали выше.