# Создание ЧПУ для категорий сайта с помощью PHP

Tags: php, mysql, seo

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать с помощью PHP и БД так, чтобы новости на сайте отображались за принципом news/название_категории/название_статьи

Если на сайте, например, есть 30 категорий.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Возможно ли создание ЧПУ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/271372/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%a7%d0%9f%d0%a3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Для каждой категории и статьи храните в БД так называемый «slug». Это краткое или полное уникальное название латиницей.
2. Во время запроса, проверяете, соответствует ли он формату `news/<category_slug>/<article_slug>`
3. Проверяете в БД, есть ли категория с запрошенным `category_slug`. Если нет – прерываете алгоритм. Если есть, получаете ID категории.
4. Проверяете в БД, есть ли статья с запрошенным `article_slug`. Если нет – прерываете алгоритм. Если есть, проверяете дополнительно, принадлежит ли статья выбранной на шаге 3 категории (по ID категории). Если не принадлежит – прерываете алгоритм. Если принадлежит, получаете ID статьи.
5. Имея ID категории и ID статьи, отображаете страницу со всем необходимым наполнением.

Иногда URL делают вида `news/<category_slug>/<article_id>-<article_slug>`. Например: `news/cats/56-my-story-about-little-cats`

В этом случае на 4 шаге в БД происходит поиск по `article_id`, а затем для полученной статьи переданный в запросе `article_slug` сравнивается с выбранным из БД `article_slug`. Это позволяет не индексировать в БД колонку `article_slug` и задавать достаточно длинные URL.

Если интересует что-то ещё – спрашивайте.

Comment: Я новичёк но хочу разобраться с такой интерестной темой, что это за такой <category_slug>/<article_id>-<article_slug> это же в URL подставляется и каким боком?, ожно ссылку на документацию или что где читать?

Comment: @ДимаПерильман, всё верно. Когда генерируете URL для статьи, то берёте `category_slug`, `article_id`, `article_slug` и соединяете их в URL вида: `news/<category_slug>/<article_id>-<article_slug>` – у Вас получится ЧПУ для статьи. Документации к подобным вопросам никакой нет – это же не технология и не какая-нибудь библиотека. Это всего лишь алгоритм составления ЧПУ.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что везде перед названием категории надо дописать приставку _slug?
P.S.Огромное спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @lovo, под slug понимается латинизированное название той или иной сущности. Например, для категории "авто" в качестве slug можно использовать "avto".

Comment: Хорошо, с этим понятно, разместил slug в БД. А по поводу пункта №2, надо создать функцию slug для начала?

Comment: @lovo, верно. Есть множество реализаций этой функции в сети. Ищите по ключевым словам «slug» и «slugify». Вот пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461406/cyrillic-transliteration-in-php

Comment: Я конечно извиняюсь за множество вопросов, т.к. я совсем новичок. category и article у нас тоже функции с обращением к БД?

Comment: @lovo, не понял вопрос. category/article – это сущности.